# Finite difference, deriving polynomials or derivatives?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I just watched [this video](https://youtu.be/vIriKhGsaPk) on finite differences, but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) is the Wikipedia page on finite differences, which seems to be talking about something entirely different. And then I found in a book a section deriving the derivatives at discrete points:

Suppose you sample a function at the discrete points $n\Delta x,n \in Z$. We sample the function $f(x) = sin x$ on the interval $[−4, 4]$ with $\Delta x = 1/4$ and plot the data points. We wish to approximate the derivative of the function on the grid points using
only the value of the function on those discrete points. From the definition of the
derivative, one is lead to the formula

$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+ \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

...and then it talks about Taylor's theorem. Is any of this related? It seems not to this beginner, it's just sharing the name *finite difference*. Also, I've seen the difference quotient described as a type of finite difference. I'm guessing the video is just a method of figuring out a polynomial from data, while the others are talking about figuring out derivatives from points when no limit can be taken due to the discrete gaps in the points. If they are related, I'd like to know how, i.e., what is the overarching principle at work here.

Comment: $F(f)$ is probably a mistype. Did you mean $f(x)$?

Comment: Corrected it....

Comment: The only question you have asked is "Is any of this related?" The answer to that is, yes, finite differences and derivatives are related. To get a better answer, you have to ask a more focussed question. What exactly is it that you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of function $f(x)$ can be approximated using formula you provided (forward difference). You can also use backward difference approximation.
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x ) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$
Both approximations have an error $O(\Delta x)$.

Central difference approximation
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{2\Delta x}$$
with the error $O(\Delta x ^ 2)$.
Calculation of errors of approximations is based on Taylor's theorem.

Comment: I was wondering more along the lines of how the polynomial from data discovery is similar to the derivative from points are similar, whether there's a theoretical underpinning linking the two.

Comment: Looks like he implictly uses higher order differences to determine if  some sequence can be described by some polynomial. I am not going to watch 1/4 hour video about particular numerical examples.

Comment: Ginsberg: Yes, so is there any overarching connection between the two? That's my central question here.